# SQL Nested Queries, Max, Grouping

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table (named Inventory) is the following:

> InventoryType,LocationID,InventoryLevel,SafetyStock,MaxLevel,ModifiedAt
>
> Erasors,1,14,3,15,11-2014
>
> Erasors,2,4,10,50,10-2014
>
> Erasors,2,5,10,50,11-2014
>
> Pencils,1,10,5,45,11-2014
>
> Pencils,2,23,15,50,11-2014
>
> Pens,1,9,10,50,11-2014
>
> Pens,2,55,10,50,12-2014

There are three primary keys: InventoryType, LocationID, and ModifiedAt.

Given a specified LocationID, I'd like the query to return all for each distinct InventoryType where the date for each tuple returned is the most recent ModifiedAt date among records for that given inventory type with the specified LocationID. Eg, LocationID = 2 would return:

> InventoryType,LocationID,InventoryLevel,SafetyStock,MaxLevel,ModifiedAt
>
> Erasors,2,5,10,50,11-2014
>
> Pencils,2,23,15,50,11-2014
>
> Pens,2,55,10,50,12-2014

My attempt thus far is the following:

```
SELECT InventoryType, LocationID, InventoryLevel,
       SafetyStock, MaxLevel, ModifiedAt
FROM Inventory
WHERE LocationID = 2 AND ModifiedAt IN
     (SELECT TOP 1 ModifiedAt 
      FROM Inventory
      WHERE LocationID = 2
      ORDER BY ModifiedAt DESC);
```

My query returns:

```
InventoryType,LocationID,InventoryLevel,SafetyStock,MaxLevel,ModifiedAt
Pens,2,55,10,50,12-2014
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT InventoryType, LocationID, InventoryLevel, SafetyStock, MaxLevel, ModifiedAt
FROM Inventory as i
WHERE LocationID = 2 AND
      ModifiedAt IN (SELECT TOP 1 i2.ModifiedAt
                     FROM Inventory as i2
                     WHERE i2.LocationID = 2 AND i2.InventoryType = i.InventoryType
                     ORDER BY i2.ModifiedAt DESC
                    );
```

Comment: My bad, transcribed ModifiedAt as MonthYear for some reason.

Anyway, this seems to do exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` for selecting distinct `InventoryType`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT InventoryType, LocationID, 
InventoryLevel, SafetyStock, MaxLevel, ModifiedAt
FROM Inventory
WHERE LocationID = 2
AND ModifiedAt IN 
(SELECT TOP 1 ModifiedAt FROM Inventory WHERE LocationID = 2 ORDER BY ModifiedAt DESC)
```